# In Node.js setting status to 404 reponds with a 304 instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my node.js app (with Express), I have a final else condition to catch unknown  paths and respond with a file named '404.html':

```
else if(req.url !== '/json' && req.url !== '/version' && req.url !==  "/json/version"){
   res.status(404).send('<script>location.href = "/404.html";</script>');
}
```

This is working fine if for example someone is trying to access a invalid path `www.myApp.com/aaldkfjd` or `www.myApp.com/aaldkfjd/jkjadklfja/dkjfakj`, which are invalid so it will go in the else and sends the '404.html' file.

but when inspecting the server response in the client,  I noticed it's a 304, instead of a 404.

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
    <title>My Awesome 404 page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/css/styles.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/images/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body style="text-align:center;">
<div id="loginDiv">
    <h1 id="loginHeader">404...We don't know that route!</h1>
</div>

<img src="images/myImageMedium.png" alt="404 image">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect that if you tell your browser's devtools not to clear the network tab when going from one page to the next, you'll find that it's a 404 (for the invalid URL) *followed by* a 304 (for the `404.html` resource).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is sending a script that redirects to the 404 page, thus the 304 status.

The best practice here would be to have node send the "My Awesome 404 page" itself.

So:

```
res.status(404).sendFile('public/404.html')
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and it returns a 404 with the file displayed (works):  res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..','/public/404.html'));   BUT oddly enough it only works with let's say 'www.myApp.com/aaldkfjd/' but NOT 'www.myApp.com/aaldkfjd/jkjadklfja/dkjfakj' and by that I mean it sends the file, but the image is not show when ther is an extra '/' so 'www.myApp.com/aaldkfjd/jkjadklfja/dkjfakj'  doesn't show the image.

Comment: in your html, use: /images/...

it is looking for the image in the subdirectory /aaldkfjd/

Comment: That worked. I'm now getting the a proper 404 response while still being redirected to the custom 404 page. Probably marking your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

The browser gets a 404 status and loads the 404 error page.

The error page contains JavaScript which causes the browser to leave the 404 page and navigate to a new page.

That page is loaded with a 304 status.

---

You should serve your actual 404 message when you output a 404 error and not redirect the client.

Answer (score -3):

you could event try the following code below.

```
else if(req.url !== '/json' && req.url !== '/version' && req.url !==  "/json/version"){ 
res.write('<script>location.href = "/404.html";</script>'); res.status(404).end();
}
```

Comment: Implemented and this still comes back with a 304 status.